# How to change a plain text separated with comma into an array in node?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have this text as my post tags:

```
  car,phone,apple,node,php
```

and I wanna convert that into an array, like this:

```
 ["car","phone","apple","node","php"]
```

and then save that into my mongodb database.

how can I do that in my server.js code?

Comment: `String's split()` would help you

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

passing `,` as an argument to `split`, will do it for you.

```
> x = "car,phone,apple,node,php"
'car,phone,apple,node,php'
> x.split(",")
[ 'car', 'phone', 'apple', 'node', 'php' ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! that works!

Comment: nice to help you -))

Answer (score 1):

```
"car,phone,apple,node,php".split(',');
```

will do the thing

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript default split function.

```js
 var stringVar = "car,phone,apple,node,php";
console.log(stringVar.split(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str ="car,phone,apple,node,php";
var arr =str.split(',');
console.log(arr);
```

split() function converts the string into array.